# Takes a long time to insert rows to database - data Parallel method

Tags: c#, web-services, ms-access

i insert data to database from terminal to **access** Through WebService

like this:

```
using (Conn = new OleDbConnection(Work_Connect))
{
    foreach (DataRow R in ds.Tables["MyCount"].Rows)
    {
        U_TermNum = TermNum;
        U_Id = Id;
        U_Bar = R["Bar"].ToString().Trim();
        U_Qty = R["Qty"].ToString().Trim();
        U_Des = R["Des"].ToString().Trim();
        U_UserName = UserName;
        U_UserID = UserID;

        SQL = "INSERT INTO MyTbl (ID,Bar,Qty,TermNum,Des,UserName,UserID) VALUES (@A,@B,@C,@D,@E,@F,@G)";

        using (OleDbCommand Cmd4 = new OleDbCommand(SQL, Conn))
        {
            Cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@A", Convert.ToInt32(U_Id));
            Cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@B", U_Bar);
            Cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C", Convert.ToDouble(U_Qty));
            Cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@D", U_TermNum);
            Cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@E", U_Des);
            Cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@F", U_UserName);
            Cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@G", U_UserID);
            Cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }

    }
```

i try to send from 20 terminal's

if i send 1--> wait 10 seconds send 2 --> wait 10 seconds --> .......... it works very fast and all teriminals ends to send after 1 minute

but if i send Parallel at ones --> it works very slow and all terminals ends after 6 minuts

why ? and how to change my code that i can send parallel and all ends fast ?

**Now I noticed that not all rows was insert to the database
(When I want to put them all in - one)
How to deal with this trouble ?**

Comment: Does using a async connection work for you? Pls see this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca56w9se.aspx

Comment: By "parallel" do you mean using the Parallel library or running some app from 20 separate clients at one time?

Comment: thanks for the help, is async connection will work on access ?

Answer (score 0):

If you find that your application is bogging down under load then using an Access back-end database might not be the right choice for your situation. Specifically:

- ACE/Jet (Access) databases are generally not recommended for use with Web applications where the number of concurrent connections can vary greatly and web traffic can "spike" the level of activity well above ACE/Jet's "comfort zone"..
- Informal discussions among Access developers tend to consider ~10 concurrent users as the point where an Access application will start to slow down, and ~25 concurrent users is often cited as the practical limit. These are very general guidelines, of course, and some Access applications can handle many more concurrent users depending on their usage patterns (e.g., mostly lookups with occasional inserts and updates).

So, if your application will regularly have ~20 concurrent connections hammering INSERTs into the database as fast as they can then then you should consider switching your database back-end to a server-based product that is better-suited to that type of activity.

Comment: I have no choice, this is what is installed at the customer computer. is there any way ?

Comment: If the Access database cannot handle the peak loads for that environment then the only workaround would be to limit those peak loads, e.g. by limiting the number of connections to your web service/application. If that is not acceptable to the client then they will need to use a database back-end that *can* handle the peak loads.